# How to hide designer error "The property xyz does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" namespace

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xaml-designer

In VS 2015 (SP3) the designer shows an error for ignorable namespaces.
In older versions (older SPs) this was not displayed as error.

The project compiles w/o errors and also in runtime there are no errors. So only the designer shows this as error.

How to remove this error from the Error List?

[image: screenshot]

Hey and don't say the Visibilty property does not exist. I know this :-) and all things marked with the d prefix shall be ignored (mc:Ignorable="d"), but does not. Thanks for your Ideas.